# How do I infer an end date in a pandas dataframe using loc

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of records in a dataframe like so:

The codes in update_code stand for

1: update to inventory

5: removed from inventory.

```
Date        id        amount   update_code
20170101     Apple     39            1
20170102     Pears     21            1
20170105     Apple     13            1
20170227     Pears                   5
```

I'm looking to create a column with a date range for every record.  For example the output should look like this:

```
Date         id        amount   update_code end_date
20170101     Apple     39            1      20170104
20170102     Pears     21            1      20170226
20170105     Apple     13            1      29990909
20170227     Pears                   5      20170227
```

Each date and record should end 1 day before the next change in the dataframe.  So the first record of 'Apple' is from 01/01/2017 until 01/04/2017 since there is a new 'Apple' record on 01/05/2017.

I've tried doing this with df loc but having trouble isolating each id.

My code so far is the following (which only infers the end date if the update_code is 5):

```
def end_date(df):
    df['end_date'] = ''
    df.loc[df['update'].isin([5]), 'endDate'] = df.Date
    return df
```

I still cannot figure out how to do the other part of inferring the end of each record and appending the dates.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you want to convert the Date column to datetime and set up an index to distinguish between different instances of 'Apples' and 'Pears').

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y%m%d')
```

I assume that your dataframe can be converted to this form.

```
df
#        Date     id  amount  update_code
#0 2017-01-01  Apple    39.0            1
#1 2017-01-02  Pears    21.0            1 
#2 2017-01-05  Apple    13.0            1        
#3 2017-02-27  Pears     NaN            5
```

Next, group by the the item id, arrange each group in the order of increasing dates, shift the dates one row back, and subtract one day from each date:

```
df['end_date'] = df.groupby('id').Date.apply(lambda x: 
                                             x.shift(-1) - pd.Timedelta(1))\
                                 .reset_index(0)['Date']
```

This operation creates a new column, which is only partially populated:

```
#        Date     id  amount  update_code   end_date
#0 2017-01-01  Apple    39.0            1 2017-01-04
#1 2017-01-02  Pears    21.0            1 2017-02-26
#2 2017-01-05  Apple    13.0            1        NaT
#3 2017-02-27  Pears     NaN            5        NaT
```

Now, replace end dates for the update code 5 with the inferred dates:

```
df.loc[df.update_code==5,'end_date'] = df.Date

#        Date     id  amount  update_code   end_date
#0 2017-01-01  Apple    39.0            1 2017-01-04
#1 2017-01-02  Pears    21.0            1 2017-02-26
#2 2017-01-05  Apple    13.0            1        NaT
#3 2017-02-27  Pears     NaN            5 2017-02-27
```

You can replace NaTs ("not-a-time"s) in the last column with sentinels, if you want:

```
df.end_date.fillna(pd.to_datetime('20990909', format='%Y%m%d'), inplace=True)
```

Comment: Nice solution ++. `df.groupby()` sorts group keys per default, so i think we can simplify it a little bit: `df.groupby('id').Date.apply(lambda x: x.shift(-1) - pd.Timedelta(1))`